# Getting The Data of a POST Request in Python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to get the skills returned after entering a Job title (such as "Process Analyst") on this website: https://match.emsiskills.com/skills/job.

After entering the job title, I observed that skills are called by a POST request. I tried matching the data required by this POST request but I keep getting a 415 error.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
skills_url = 'https://match.emsiskills.com/api/emsi-services/profiles/rankings/skills'
data = '{"filter":{"title":["15.74"]},"rank":{"by":"profiles","limit":60,"min_profiles":1}}'
r = requests.post(skills_url, data=data, json=True)
```

This returns a 415 error as mentioned earlier.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 415 is incompatible media - try setting header Content-Type: application/json

Comment: You're calling post incorrectly. It should be, e.g., `r = requests.post(url, json={'a': 2, 'b': 'asdf'})`. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks a lot for the tip. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JustinEzequiel comment, it turns out I was using the calling post method incorrectly.

Here is the updated and working code:

```
import requests
skills_url = 'https://match.emsiskills.com/api/emsi-services/profiles/rankings/skills'
data = {"filter":{"title":["15.74"]},"rank":{"by":"profiles","limit":60,"min_profiles":1}}
r = requests.post(skills_url, json=data)
```